# My Azure Function should throw an exception in case of empty string

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httprequest, http-get, azure-function-app

The code of the `Run` method of my Azure Function is this:

```
public static void Run([HttpTrigger("get")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {
   string parameter = req.Query["parameter"];
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Parameter must be set.");
   }
   log.LogInformation(parameter);
}
```

I have the following cases when running the Function and passing the parameter to the HTTP request:

- HTTP GET without parameter (`/api/ServiceBusOutput`): exception (correct)
- HTTP GET with not set parameter (`/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter`): exception (correct)
- HTTP GET with parameter as empty string (`/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter=""`): **success but it should fail** (the URL becomes `/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter=%22%22`)
- HTTP GET with parameter as string (`/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter="something"`): success (correct)

How can I do to make the third test to fail?

Comment: The reason it fails is because the value of "" is a valid value for a parameter from a purely URI perspective.  The behavior of the Azure function is also correct, you need to take care of the logic inside the function

Comment: Have you tried [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1) ? BTW `%22` is a urlencoded `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `""` is a valid query string parameter. String values would not be passed in quotes via a URL.

For example, if you want to receive the word `something` as the parameter, it would be passed as `/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter=something`.

If you are trying to test an empty string value any of the following would work.

`/api/ServiceBusOutput?parameter=
/api/ServiceBusOutput`